# Permutation: divide 713 0's and 31 1's over 744 different positions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

So I need to figure out all the possible permutations to divide 31 1's and 713 0's over 744 positions (all zeroes and ones are exactly the same). I created the following code to create all permutations of 0's and 1's over 744 positions and my idea was to delete those lines which do not sum to 31, but I get a memory overflow. Any way to do this more efficiently?

```
from itertools import product
comb = list(product([0,1], repeat=744))    
print(comb)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "divide 0 and 1"? Do you want to get a sequence of 744 numbers, 31 are 1 and rest are 0?

Comment: Sorry, I just cast the deciding vote to close the question but then read it again and it's perfectly clear. I'm voting to reopen it.

Comment: I'll post an answer once the question's reopened, but for now: Creating the list is the main problem - it stores everything in memory including the items you don't want. The first improvement you could make is iterating over `product()` instead of making a list. But ultimately you'll want to rethink how you're approaching this from a combinatorics perspective. There's a really easy way to get what you want, which sokato's answer hints at.

Comment: Scratch "really easy". I've tried it myself and haven't found a way yet. Though I don't have much math experience.

Comment: @wjandrea If it's just a list of 744 numbers with 31 1's, that seems pretty trivial. Could you explain what the question means? I have a feeling it's more complicated than that.

Comment: @iz_ I think it is just that actually (31 1's in 744 numbers), though there was an edit that changed the wording and made it sound more complicated.

Comment: @wjandrea The only issue is there is a *lot* of combinations. In general, this problem can be solved by iterating through `itertools.combinations(range(744), 31)` to get tuples of indices where the 1's will appear, then setting those elements to 1 in a list of 744 0's. Unfortunately, there are `744 C 31` combinations, which is `6.7378004e+54 `...

Comment: exactly, 31 1´s in 744 numbers that is my goal. As Iz? has pointed out, the problem is just too big and it is not possible to solve with a current desktop computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a combinatorics problem. Finding all of the permutations seems a like it would be quite expensive for the numbers that you are dealing with as it is a really large number. There are algorithms designed to determine permutations like Heap's algorithm. In this case, you could run the algorithm and only keep a representation of the positions that sum to thirty one. You would need to store these though which may cause the same error. A large part of the issue is you're trying to keep all of the possibilities which is a huge number.

You could also attempt to start with an array containing only 31 1's then you'd need shuffle them to obtain the permutations. This would be less expensive spatially than storing all of the permutations at least.

If you intend to find the number of potential combinations?

If that is the case you can consider n choose k maybe e.g. 744 choose 31.